# How do I make a dropdown in datatable not overlay?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having issue when i add a dropdown menu in datatable. I can open the dropdown but it will overlay with the pagination and other records.

You can view an [image here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LAg-s0blQjpCr0KfcmgbUNgTQF2llO28/view?usp=sharing)

```html
<table class="table dataTable table-striped table-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="disabled-sorting">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="testing">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="notification" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        test
                                    </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="notification">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I fix the dropdown?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as a 'fix'? It should open upwards for the rows at the bottom? It should be opaque not to let you see the underlying parts of the table? Either way it's up to your implementation of a drop-down and you, unfortunately didn't share relevant code to track down the issue.

Comment: Can you please try with z-index CSS property